# How to conditionally render apex:outputPanel based on two values: a checkbox and a List of Strings?

Tags: visualforce

I'm having an issue trying to achieve this:

> When the invoice is created with these conditions:
>
> Currency is USD and
>
> billing country
> is United States, Canada, China, Hong Kong, India, Japan, Philippines,
> Singapore, Taiwan, United Arab Emirates, Australia, New Zealand,
> Austria, Belgium, Bulgaria, Croatia, Czech Republic, Denmark, Estonia,
> Finland, France, Germany, Gibraltar, Guernsey, Greece, Hungary,
> Iceland, Ireland, Isle of Man, Italy, Jersey, Latvia, Liechtenstein,
> Luxembourg, Malta, Netherlands, Norway, Poland, Portugal, Romania,
> Slovakia, Slovenia, Spain, Sweden, Switzerland, United Kingdom.
>
> Use
> these bank details:
>
> Account Holder: FocusEconomics SLU Bank Name: TransferWise

So I did this and it's working fine, but just with one condition:

```
<apex:outputPanel layout="block" rendered="

{!invoice.Contract__r.InvoiceInUSD__c}">
                                   <p><b><u>Wire Transfer</u></b></p>
                                    <p>Account Holder: FocusEconomics SLU<br/>
                                    Bank Name: TransferWise<br/>
                            
</apex:outputPanel>
```

My question is: How can I add a second condition to check the billingCountry based on a List of Countries that I have to define.

I know I can create the List of countries in the controller but I don't know how to render my apex:outputPanel based on the first condition (currency being USD) AND billingCountry being contained inside the List of countries I will create in the controller.

Could anyone please help me out ??

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a new attribute in the controller for this:

```
public Boolean renderList {get; set;}
private Set<String> allowedCountries = new Set<String>{'Country1', 'Country2',...};
//controller constructor
public Controller(){
    renderList = record.InvoiceInUSD__c && allowedCountries.contains(record.BillingCountry);
}
```

Then your VF page can just do

```
<apex:outputPanel rendered="{!renderList}">
```

Just make sure you're handling all the logic to set `renderList` in the constructor, otherwise you'll have to rerender.

Comment: Exactly what I needed ... many thanks Jeff :)